# using help Text in visualforce

Tags: community

I have a Visualforce page which consists of questions and inputFields below the question .I want to use Help Text for that field so as to display the Text in place of question.How do i achieve it without using `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` ?
My code:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <div class="questions">
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helptext="{!$ObjectType.Survey__c.Fields.Impact_of_visit__c.InlineHelpText}">
            {!$ObjectType.Survey__c.Fields.Impact_of_visit__c.label}
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Survey__c.Fields.Impact_of_visit__c.Label}" />
             <apex:inputField value="{!decision.Impact_of_visit__c}" />
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </div>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Its that i have to display 5 questions from the help text of the particular field.And if i use it in `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` ,i get blocks in the page which i dont want to display on the page.

Comment: Have you already tried something you could show ?

Comment: And could you clarify why you don't want to use the <apex:pageBlockSectionItem> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
We can add helptext in PaeblockTable as well using jquery:

<apex:page standardController="Case">
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>   
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock mode="edit"  tabStyle="Case" >                                     
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Subject" columns="1" id="subject" collapsible="false" >
              <!-- Configure your help text from Field Help text-->                                                                         
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="{!$ObjectType.Case.fields.subject.inlineHelpText}">
                  <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Case.fields.subject.label}"/>                                       
                  <apex:outputPanel >
                      <apex:inputField value="{!case.subject}" />               
                  </apex:outputPanel>                                         
              </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:pageBlock>

       <script>
                 var elementToAppend = '<span class="helpButton" id="example-title-_help"><img src="/s.gif" class="helpOrb" style="width: 20px!important;height:15px!important;"/></span>';
                 $("[id$='subject']").find('h3').after(elementToAppend);
                 sfdcPage.setHelp('example-title', 'Demo help Text');
        </script>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>

Code referred from: http://salesforcebytes.blogspot.in/2015/01/add-helpbutton-in-pageblock-using.html
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean you want the field helptext displayed as a label? You could do it like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection >
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
             <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Survey__c.Fields.Impact_of_visit__c.InlineHelpText}" />
             <apex:inputField value="{!decision.Impact_of_visit__c}" />
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

So in the pageblocksectionitem you can put any values. The first component will be used as label, the second as field value.

Comment: @Simmi once check the below link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181401&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

One more way by which you can use helptext as field label and get rid of `<apex:pageblockSectionItem>` too by using `label` attribute of inputField. Try this:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
   <apex:pageBlockSection >
       <apex:inputField value="{!decision.Impact_of_visit__c}" label="{!$ObjectType.Survey__c.Fields.Impact_of_visit__c.InlineHelpText}" />
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

But still if it is about blocks in page, then avoid using `<apex:pageBlockSection>`. Try this way:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
   <div class="questions">
      <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Survey__c.Fields.Impact_of_visit__c.InlineHelpText}" />
      <apex:inputField value="{!decision.Impact_of_visit__c}" />
   </div>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: @simmi if you like an answer you can show your appreciation for the person taking their time to answer it by clicking the 'up' arrow next to the answer. And the answer that answers your question best  can be 'accepted' by you so that future users with the same problem can quickly find the best solution.